# Keyword search not working

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a simple sql search that searches terms by keywords. Only, I have to type in the full key word phase for a result to show.

index.php

```
$term = $_GET['q'];
$term = strip_tags($term);
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);

require_once("<PATHTOFILE>\\dbconnect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Search WHERE Keywords LIKE '{$term}' LIMIT 15";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("couldn't apply search");

<h1>Results for '<?php echo $term; ?>'</h1>
<br>
<ul>
    <?php 
        if($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    ?>
        <li><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></li>

    <?php 
            }
        } 
        if($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            ?>No Results.<?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

sql table structure:
[image: capture]

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: surround with % `'%{$term}%'`

Comment: You're also mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. So that won't work. Plus, it will then need to be placed after you've connected to DB using the `i` equivalent `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and passing connection parameter to the function.

Comment: When I did that, the whole term variable became blank.

Comment: What's in here `dbconnect.php`? DB connection?

Comment: `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","<username>","<password>","<dbname>") or die("Could not connect to database:".$con->connect_error);`

Comment: You said when you did that... it was blank; did "what" exactly; what syntax did you use "exactly" and where did you place it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71305/discussion-between-krii-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

That function does not intermix with `mysqli_` functions.

You need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$term);` placed after your connection.

Along with `'%{$term}%'` as stated by Lashane in comments.

Comment: Then only thing that should be mixed is....nah, just joking. The only thing 20 y/o scotch mixes with is good company. *Mornin' Ralph*.

Comment: *Aye Cap'n*, ye have that spot on the glass' rim matey! *Mornin' Sam!* @JayBlanchard